# How do you open (actually open) a text file in Excel using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I know how to read/write from/to a text file. But those routines don't actually visibly open the text file. I want to be able to open the text file so I can make edits directly (in the Notepad application), rather than through a macro.

To clarify - I am not looking to import the data from the text file into Excel. I just want to open the text file from within Excel - but the actual edit of the text file will be in Notepad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried it like this:

```
Sub OpenTextFile() 

On Error GoTo 1 
ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "C:\Windows\test.txt", NewWindow:=True 
Exit Sub 
1:       MsgBox Err.Description
```

End Sub

Source: http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=341

*P.S. Sorry, I'm currently on a machine without excel installed, so I can't test it until monday...so please try it*